# How do I resolve gcloud gmail-api watch 400 (Bad Request)?

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-managed-vm

**Context:**

Following instructions ([here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)) for setting up GMail push notifications; and ([here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch)) for setting up a GMail Watch on a Pub/Sub topic.

(Pub/Sub topic and subscription has already been created; API client access to the app has been granted in Google Apps)

**Problem:**

Executing the following code results in the following (JSON) error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "failedPrecondition",
            "message": "Bad Request"
        }],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

**Resolutions Attempted:**

1. Tried including the GMail account as the `sub` parameter, while creating the credentials service.
2. Recreated Pub/Sub topic & subscription.
3. Added domain to Google Developers Console Project.

**Code:**

```
import logging
import httplib2
import json

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# Read in service credentials form file
with open('secrets.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

client_email = data["client_email"]
private_key = data["private_key"]

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email,
                                            private_key,
                                            'https://mail.google.com/')


def build_gmail_service(credentials):
    # Build a authorized, Gmail service object.
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)


def watch_gmail(service, user_id='me'):
    request = {
        'topicName': 'projects/app/topics/gmail',
        'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
        'labelFilterAction': "include"
    }

    try:
        # Make the request.
        response = service.users().watch(userId=user_id,
                                         body=request).execute()

        # Print the results of the request
        if 'error' in response:
            # The API executed, but the script returned an error.
            error = response['error']['details'][0]
            print "Script error! Message: {0}".format(error['errorMessage'])
        else:
            # response successful
            return response
    except errors.HttpError as e:
        # The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
        logging.error('An error occurred: %s', e.content)


service = build_gmail_service(credentials)
watch_gmail(service, 'user@google_apps_domain.com')
```

Comment: Please update question to provide full error response (i.e. the HTTP body)

Comment: @EricDeFriez: Thanks for your response Eric. I've added the full error response.

Comment: Where?  I only see the python stacktrace generated by your program, that doesn't contain the full HTTP response body.  try logging the exception.content or exception.get_reason()

Comment: @EricDeFriez: From my deduction, it seems the error is happening before the response returns (i.e. there is an error in the request.) I've also updated my code and included the JSON error response.

Comment: @EricDeFriez: One of my objectives is to automate Google Drive attachment based on parameters in the e-mail subject. Instead of the GMail API, does it make more sense to use IMAP and SMTP?